# An exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle11g

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong here? I am facing **`Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException` exception** and when I clicked to view details I saw

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'PRC_ABCD_GETALL' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I have a store procedure like this

```
PROCEDURE PRC_ABCD_GETALL (resultset_out OUT TYPES.cursorType)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN 
resultset_out FOR SELECT * FROM ABCD;
END PRC_ABCD_GETALL;
```

And my C# code is like this

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnn))
{
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "PRC_ABCD_GETALL";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("resultset_out", OracleDbType.RefCursor, 
    ParameterDirection.Output);
    OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();              
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        result.Add(Construct(rdr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use sys_refcursor instead TYPES.cursorType in your procedure's declaration. 
Types.cursorType isn't the same.

You can try changing the c# invocation data type instead of changing it on store procedure:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnn)){
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "PRC_ABCD_GETALL";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("resultset_out", OracleType.Cursor, 
ParameterDirection.Output);
OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();              
while (rdr.Read())
{
    result.Add(Construct(rdr));
}}
```

Comment: thanks for reply christian :) . I can't change TYPES.cursorType cause it's in my production site. so is there any way to change in C# code? like this cmd.Parameters.Add("resultset_out", OracleDbType.Cursortypes, 
    ParameterDirection.Output).I am fresher in asp.net and oracle store procedure so i don't know about this. any info on this will be halpfull for me. once again thanks for reply :)

Comment: Hi @saha.jan , I update my answer with other option. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Hi christian thanks for your answer :) . let me try this way.many many thanks :)

Comment: Hi christian I added this cmd.Parameters.Add("resultset_out", OracleType.Cursor, 
ParameterDirection.Output) and I'm getting this error 'OracleDbType' does not contain a definition for 'Cursor'. any sollution for this?